# Is it possible, connecting two microcontrollers via Bluetooth Modules?

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller, avr, uart

there are several tutorials on interfacing Microcontrollers with PC / Android Devices using Bluetooth modules.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEvk0.png
However, seeing this image at https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics this question aroused in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to connect two MCU via bluetooth. You've got plenty of bluetooth module (HC-05, RN42) from different manufacturers. They're essentially drop-in replacement for RS232 cables and they work via a UART.

Comment: I am new to microcontroller programming, and have poor understanding of Hardware; for Mobile to microcontroller interfacing, as I've seen in tutorials the pairing between bluetooth is done manually; but if both the modules are connected to microcontrollers then how they are paired.

Comment: These modules are configurable via a standard USART (universal sync/async receiver/transceiver) module. If you have an Arduino or any MicroController, you probably have access to a USART. You simply connect a BT module to each MCU, then via USART, you send AT commands at a specified baud rate to configure the modules (1master, 1slave) and thats it.

Datasheet : 'http://www.exp-tech.de/service/datasheet/HC-Serial-Bluetooth-Products.pdf'